# How to make a drop-down navbar section in html work only when hovered over not when clicked on?

Tags: html

This is a code for a part of navbar I am trying to make. For the "our tracks" section, I have a link for it, but it doesn't open because clicking on it opens the drop-down menu. I want this menu to open only when it is hovered on, not clicked on.

```
<div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" 
         href="our%20tracks.html">Our Tracks<b> class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Robotics</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Automation</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you got to write your own custom JQuery code to overwrite the default bootstrap behavior, like so:

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```